# what's wrong with this yaml object?

Tags: yaml, jekyll

I'm working with jekyll and trying to define an object in the front matter for a post file:

```
person: {
    name: Bob Smith,
    face: facepic.jpg,
    friendlyName: bob-smith,
}
```

and in the template, I'm trying to access the variable `name` like so:

```
{{person.name}}
```

But I get blank. I've also tried `{{post.person.name}}` How do I access the variable name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

syntax errors

```
person: {
    name: Bob Smith,
    face: facepic.jpg,
    friendlyName: bob-smith,\\extra comma
}
```

`{{post.person.name}}`\you need post as a `parent` object or, `{{page.person.name}}` will work by default.

Comment: `{{post.person.name}}` didn't work, but `{{page.person.name}}` does. Shouldn't the `post` var be the parent?

Comment: as you mentioned post is a file so it will not work for post. you need to specify post as a `parent` and `child` as a person and name.

 `page>person>name` it will be the hierarchy of current situation so `{{page.person.name}}` works

Comment: you're right. i thought `page.varname` was for pages and `post.varname` for posts. confusingly, posts are pages in jekyll!

Answer (score 1):

Except the fact that you have an extra coma after `friendlyName: bob-smith`, you can simplify your front matter by writing :

```
person:
    name: Bob Smith
    face: facepic.jpg
    friendlyName: bob-smith
```

See [yaml specification](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2759963)